# I am getting context value undefined in the child component using contextType in an expo app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to use context api in my app, the way i am trying to use is https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype

here's a snack that I need to fix https://snack.expo.io/@mohmdalfaha/contexttype-example the context value is always undefined??

Comment: I have fixed this by just removing {} from {AppContext}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error in your import in child component. As you are exporting AppContext as default you can't import in {}. You can import constant in {}. 
Here's a snack for that https://snack.expo.io/ByQkOVgXS